# Looping 'raster' package functions over each multi-polygon feature in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, r-raster

I am trying to loop several functions from the 'raster' package, namely, crop(), mask(), reclassify() and unstack()/as.list(). I have ten raster layers that share the same extent and data type; they correspond to land cover over 10 time-points. I want to create individual list variables for each output of crop() -> mask() -> reclassify() -> as.list(). I was able to pipe the process for 1 polygon feature, but I need to be able to loop it for each of the 10 polygon features stored in the multipolygon Shapefile, such that I can save each output list according to a specified naming convention.

Thank you and please advise. I share my code below.

EDIT: I am wondering if a for-loop is the right way to go about this, or would an lapply approach be better?

```
# Load libraries
library(raster)             # for raster processing
library(rgdal)              # for raster/vector processing
library(sf)                 # for Shapefile processing

# Stack 10 rasters together
raster.stack = stack( 
  raster("path/raster1.tif"),
  raster("path/raster2.tif"),
  raster("path/raster3.tif"),
  raster("path/raster4.tif"),
  raster("path/raster5.tif"),
  raster("path/raster6.tif"),
  raster("path/raster7.tif"),
  raster("path/raster8.tif"),
  raster("path/raster9.tif"),
  raster("path/raster10.tif")
)

# Prepare reclassification codes from 9-class raster to 3-class raster
reclasscodes = c(
  0,0, # no data 
  1,1,
  2,1,
  3,1,
  4,1,
  5,2,
  6,2,
  7,3,
  8,3,
  9,3
)

# Convert reclass codes list into n x 2 matrix
reclassmatrix = matrix(reclasscodes, ncol=2, byrow = T)

# Load multipolygon vector Shapefile
multipolygon = shapefile("path/multipolygon.shp") # Shapefile is made of n polygons

# Example subset Shapefile to polygon_1 using attribute "ID"
polygon_1 = subset(multipolygon,ID=="D-4")

# Create output for polygon_1
list_polygon_1 =
  raster.stack %>%
  crop(y = polygon_1) %>%              # crop to bounds
  mask(mask = polygon_1) %>%           # mask to polygon cutline
  reclassify(rcl = reclassmatrix) %>%  # reclassify to 3-class
  as.list() # functions the same as unstack() where raster brick is converted to list of raster layers
# I use %>% because I do not want to save any of the intermediate outputs.
# Resultant output is a variable list for polygon_1 named 'list_polygon_1' which is exactly what I want.
# Worked perfectly.

# How do I repeat this process for polygon_1 to polygon n?

# My attempt
for (i in 1:nrow(multipolygon)) {
  raster.stack %>%
  crop(y = multipolygon[i,]) %>%
  mask(mask = multipolygon[i,]) %>%
  reclassify(rcl = reclassmatrix) %>%
  as.list() %>% # up till here it is the same steps as before for polygon_1
  # now I want to save each list output as a separate variable according to i, e.g. list_polygon_2, list_polygon_3 etc.
  assign(paste(multipolygon$ID, i, sep = '_')) # assign a naming convention for each output variable 
}
# Does not work. Even without the last line of code "..assign(paste(...))" there is no output variable from the as.list() line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal self-contained reproducible example.

Example data

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 

xy1 <- xy2 <- xy3 <- matrix(c(10,17, 6,10,71,60,62,71), ncol=2)
xy2[,1] <- xy2[,1] + 30
xy3[,2] <- xy3[,2] - 30
p <- spPolygons(xy1, xy2, xy3)
#plot(r, 1)
#lines(p)
```

What you are after

```
rm = matrix(c(0,100,0,100,150,2,150,255,3), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

out <- list()
for (i in 1:length(p)) {
    x <- crop(s, p[i,])
    x <- mask(x, p[i,])
    out[[i]] <- reclassify(x, rm)
}
```

What you are saying about unstack does not make sense (and unlist does not work). I would advise against it, but you could do

```
out2 <- lapply(out, unstack)
```

I am not sure what you are really after. If you want the cell values you can make it much simpler (no need for a loop) and do

```
r <- reclassify(s, rm)
e <- extract(r, p)
```

To your question about lapply vs a loop. In terms of performance that rarely matters. lapply can be concise, but in cases like this, writing a loop is better as it is easier to read, and write, especially if you do not use `%>%`.

Comment: Thanks Robert, your suggestion was extremely insightful. Thank you especially for the well structured response. Forgive me for the lack of clarity and reproducibility in my post. I adapted your code up till out2 <- lapply(out, unstack) and it worked. To clarify on what I am after; I require a list of raster layers clipped to each polygon. I want it structured this way to analyse them individually later on. Thank you!